# How can I get the output of the echo command?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile with a RUN instruction like this:

```
RUN echo "$PWD"
```

When generating the Docker image I only get this in console:

```
 Step 6/17 : RUN echo "$PWD" 
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0e27924953b9
```

How can I get the output of the echo command in my console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line in the `dockerfile` creates a new layer in the resulting filesystem. Unless a modification is made to your `dockerfile` that hasn't previously been encountered, Docker optimizes the build by reusing existing layers that have previously been built. You can see these intermediate images with the command `docker images --all`.

This means that Docker only needs to build from the 1st changed line in the `dockerfile` onwards, saving much time with repeated builds on a well-crafted `dockerfile`. You've already built this layer in a previous build, so it's being skipped and taken from cache.

```
docker build --no-cache .
```

should prevent the build process from using cached layers.

Change the final path parameter above to suit your environment.

Comment: You beat me by a min :-)